# Converting JavaScript AJAX Web API query to PHP CURL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl, arcgis-js-api

I have a functional AJAX query against my company's [arcGIS's generateToken query](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/server-admin-api/generateToken.html) like so:

```
    var u = "CENTRAL\\myusername";
    var p = "myp@ssword"; 
    var payload = {
        username: u,
        password: p,
        client: 'referer',
        referer: 'https://mycompany.com/myapp',
        expiration: '60',
        format: 'json',
    };
    var tokenUrl = 'https://gis.mycompany.com/public/tokens/generateToken';
    $.ajax({
        url: tokenUrl,
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'text',
        data: payload,
        success: function(data){
            token = data;
            console.log(token)
        }
    });
```

I need to rewrite this to be in my PHP backend - however, `curl_getinfo` says I have an HTTP200 but the `$result` is always

> Invalid request 
>   Usage: https://gis.mycompany.com/arcgis/tokens?request=gettoken&username=username&password=password&
>   Usage: https://gis.mycompany.com/arcgis/tokens/generateToken?username=username&password=password&
>   Usage: https://gis.mycompany.com/arcgis/tokens/gettoken.html

from the endpoint. Here's my implementation:

```
    $GISuser = "CENTRAL\\myusername";
    $GISpassword = "myp@ssword";
    $GISurl = "https://gis.mycompany.com/public/tokens/generateToken";
    $payload = array(
        "username" => $GISuser,
        "password" => $GISpassword,
        "client" => "referer",
        "referer" => 'https://mycompany.com/myapp',
        "expiration" => "60",
        "format" => "json"
    );

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $GISurl);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    echo $result;
```

Is there a difference between AJAX and CURL web API queries that I am missing to get this to work?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I overlooked something too... but that looks like it should work. But you say the API server says the request is bad? Is that an API error, or a Server error? Could you paste full `curl_error($curl)` ?

Comment: if I had to guess, I'd say try adding a user-agent string. this would be set by the browser making the ajax call, but not necessarily set by curl

Comment: Updated my question - it seems I actually do get HTTP200 as per `curl_getinfo` and `curl_error` is empty. The `$result` is posted above.

Comment: You could try wrapping `$payload` in `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($payload));` ... as passing an array MAY be changing the enctype to multi-part (*NOTE: Passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will encode the data as multipart/form-data, while passing a URL-encoded string will encode the data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.)

Comment: @IncredibleHat that was it, thank you! If you make an answer I will upvote and accept!

Comment: Good to know that was it. I did a mass search for my curl usage, and only in ONE spot do I pass the $array directly without using build query. Mental note :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try wrapping `$payload` as:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($payload));
```

... as passing an array can be changing the enctype to multi-part which your API does not like.

From the PHP Page: 
*NOTE: Passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will encode the data as multipart/form-data, while passing a URL-encoded string will encode the data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.